# Creating a logout functionality in Django, however I am getting a HTTP Error 405 when trying to load the page. How do I fix it?

Tags: python, django

I am creating a blog site. I have found out you are now supposed to use a POST request for Logout, however I did this and I am not sure where I have gone wrong.

Here is the relevant code:

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path, include
from users import views as user_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/', user_views.register, name='register'),
    path('profile/', user_views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

logout.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h2>You have been logged out</h2>
    <div class="border-top pt-3">
        <form action="{% url 'logout' %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Logout</button>
        </form>
        <small class="text-muted">
            <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In Again</a>
        </small>
    </div> 
{% endblock content %}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import UserRegisterForm

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to log in.')
            return redirect('login')
    else:    
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render (request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})

@login_required
def profile(request):
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html')
```

Even tried using Chatgpt to help me, and yet, not sure what the problem is.

Was expecting the post request thing to work.

Answer (score 0):

A Django project should have a project level urls.py which is automatically created for you when you create your Django project. This file is in the same directory as your settings.py.

You also need to have your app's urls.py which should be in the same directory as your app. You seem to be mixing up both of them. I assume you are using Django's default auth. Please see https://medium.com/@bsurajbh/django-default-user-authentication-7c6108da73fa and follow the steps to resolve your issue. Notice the defining of urls patterns in the project level and app level urls.py.

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple

Go to nav.html

replace the logout button class with the following code :

```
            <li class="nav-item">
               
        <form method="post" action="{% url 'user-logout' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button type="submit" class="nav-link text-white" style="background: none; border: none; cursor: pointer;">
                Logout
            </button>
        </form>
            </li>
```

This error will be resolved